# Creating a new column based on matching value of 2 columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes using which I need to create 3 rd dataframe.

1st Dataframe looks like this:

```
route_id   entity_id_1      
 r1           1                  
 r1           4          
 r1           5
```

2nd Dataframe looks like this:

```
route_id    entity_id_2
  r1          4
  r1          7
  r1          8
  r1          9
```

The created 3rd dataframe should look like:

```
route id    compliance   
  r1           1/6
```

**Explanation:**

For a particular route_id, compliance is calculated as (no. of matching values/ total no. of distinct entity_ids)

Here, entity_1 in 1st dataframe and entity_2 in 2nd dataframe are matched.

> no. of matching values = 1  ('4' is the only entity_id which is
>   present in both dataframes for route_id 'r1')
>
> total no. of distinct entity_ids present in both dataframes = 6 (which
>   are, 1,4,5,7,8,9 for route_id 'r1')

Comment: What you have tried so far to get 3rd DataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'route_id':['r1','r1','r1'], 'entity_id_1':[1,4,5]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'route_id':['r1','r1','r1','r1'], 'entity_id_1':[4,7,8,9]})
```

Assuming sample data in above dataframe, try below

```
target_df = df1.groupby('route_id').apply(lambda x: x.entity_id_1.isin(df2[df2.route_id==x.route_id.values[0]]['entity_id_1']).sum()/len(np.unique(x.entity_id_1.tolist()+df2[df2.route_id==x.route_id.values[0]]['entity_id_1'].tolist()))).reset_index(name='compliance')
```

This will give desired output, `print(target_df)`:

```
route_id  compliance
0       r1    0.166667
```